# Low Stock Report Daily Email

Tags: magento-1.8, inventory, reports, out-of-stock, email-reminders

Within the reporting section I can see that there is a report for products which are low in stock but is there functionality to have a daily email of this report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No,** In default magento don't have this functionality. But by some code you can make it.

Setup a cron job for daily e-mail & do a filter with product collection as below for the email content:

```
$resourceCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$resourceCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        array('_inventory_table'=>'cataloginventory_stock_item'),
        "_inventory_table.product_id = e.entity_id ",
        array('qty')
    )->order(array('_inventory_table.qty ASC'));

Zend_Debug::dump($collection->getData()) ;
```